# Show that $\left| z + \sqrt{z^2 + c^2} \right| > c$ for $\operatorname{Re}(z) > 0$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

I have encountered this seemingly obvious yet bizarre-to-show inequality: $$\left| z + \sqrt{z^2 + c^2} \right| > c$$ for $z \in \Bbb C$ such that $\operatorname{Re}(z) > 0$ and $c > 0$. I've tried the reverse triangular inequality but it hasn't helped. How do you show this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that the branch of $\sqrt{z^2 + c^2}$ is chosen such that $\operatorname{Re} \sqrt{z^2 + c^2} > 0$ (otherwise the claim is wrong).

Then
$$
\left| z + \sqrt{z^2 + c^2} \right|^2 = |z|^2 + |z^2+c^2| + 2 \operatorname{Re} \left( \bar z \cdot\sqrt{z^2 + c^2}\right) \\
\ge  |z|^2 + (c^2  - |z|^2) + 2 \operatorname{Re} \left( \bar z\cdot\sqrt{z^2 + c^2}\right) \\
 = c^2 + 2 \operatorname{Re} \left( \bar z\cdot\sqrt{z^2 + c^2}\right)
$$
so that is is sufficient to show that
$$ \tag{*}
\operatorname{Re} \left( \bar z \cdot\sqrt{z^2 + c^2}\right) > 0 \, .
$$
Now observe that if $z$ lies in the first quadrant then $\sqrt{z^2 + c^2}$ is in the first quadrant as well, and $\bar z$ is in the forth quadrant, so that the product $\bar z \cdot\sqrt{z^2 + c^2}$ is in the right half-plane. A similar argument works if $z$ lies in the forth quadrant, or on the positive real axis. In any case, $(*)$ holds.

Comment: Could you please explain in more details how has the branch cut been chosen to ensure $\operatorname { Re}(\sqrt {z^2+c^2})>0$?

Comment: @user: $z$ is in the right half-plane, so that $z^2$ and  $w=z^2 + c^2$ are in $\Bbb C \setminus (-\infty, 0]$. If we write $w = |w| e^{i\arg w}$ with the *principal value* of the argument ($-\pi < \arg w <  \pi$) then $\sqrt w = \sqrt{|w|} e^{i \arg w/2}$  is in the right half-plane.

Comment: Thank you Martin!